# Network icon missing in Win10 professional

Tags: windows-10, networking

The network icon in the taskbar is missing in my computer.just like this:
[taskbar now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiB7z.png)
If i click the network icon in the notification bar,like this:
[notification bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqOOs.png)
It appears like this:
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePegp.png)
It seems like that the wifi function has gone.However,i can get access to the default wifi.I can browse the web,but some application say I'm not online.
Moreover,when i try to get access to the network by a PPPoE client,dialing failed.

**Attention**
Before things went wrong,i did nothing special with my computer,just edited my homework and shutdown my computer as normal.And when i open it today,the bad thing happens.
I know i can allow a icon to appear in my taskbar by change the setting,but in fact it's already be allowed.
The similar thing has happened in the past,and i believe that's because my C driver was out of capacity,which led to a operating system update failure.But this time my C driver's memory is suffcient and there isn't any update.So i believe the reason this time is not as same as before.

If you need any information that may help you judge while i don't mention above,please tell me.
Any advice will receive my sincere gratitude.

Comment: Run DISM / SFC and test.   ......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: sorry,it doesn't work

Comment: If DISM did not work then you need to a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.    .....    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Go to run menu and type:

[image]

Now inside device manager uninstall all of the network adapters one by one:
(don't worry these automatically re-install)

[image]

Now reboot your computer

When computer reboots, search for CMD in your start menu and right click > open as administrator:

[image]

Inside the CMD window copy and paste the following commands:

•   Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

•   Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

•   Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

•   Flush DNS resolver cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

•   Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

•   Flush routing table (reboot required):

```
route /f
```

Now reboot the computer again and hopefully your problem is solved.